# How to delete session data after a background task has occured

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session-variables

I am building an e-commerce site with Ruby on Rails version 5.1. The site allows a user to compare up to three products.  This is achieved by storing the product id's in a session array, then querying the db for those products.

I have a scenario where an automated task will run and will remove a product from stock.  This is just simply setting a flag to false on the product table in the db.

My question is: Is there a way to automate the removal of the product id in the session data for product compare if the product goes out of stock. I know I could probably do a check on the application controller, but I was hoping that there could be a more elegant approach?

Comment: what do you use as session storage?

Comment: Maybe if you don't store the session data in a cookie (i.e. client side).

Comment: In my opinion, it sounds like you're relying too much on session data. You'll also need to consider what happens when a product is deleted. It sounds ripe for further concerns. Adding a dedicated model that represents a product comparison stored in a session (ie. SessionProductComparison) may help reveal that elegance you're looking for (and hopefully wrap in tests). Unfortunately, as others have noted, much may depend on _how_ you're storing sessions.